# Prove by induction: $\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{2}{3!}+\cdots+\frac{n}{(n+1)!}=\frac{n!-1}{n!}$

Tags: summation, induction, factorial

> Prove
>   $$\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{2}{3!}+\cdots+\frac{n}{(n+1)!}=\frac{n!-1}{n!}.$$

My problem with this is that it doesn't hold for the base case: $n=1$. This question is from the book "Abstract Algebra" by Charles Pinter (Page 212, exercise 7). When I go about proving it, I can't reach my goal which is $\frac{(n+1)!-1}{(n+1)!}=1-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$, for $n=n+1$.

Comment: You must consider as a first step $n=2$ instead $n=1$.

Comment: As pointed out by Wythagoras, the formula supplied in Pinter's book is not correct--I got out my copy of the book and found the exercise (I put the information concerning the exercise in the question). Indeed, there is an error, something rather easily fixed though. And you now have several answers that should help you see how to solve the problem. But I can see how this problem would have annoyed you since most books have correct formulae. One thing I like to do whenever I buy a textbook is find the most recent errata, often published online. It will help you save some head scratching.

Comment: You can also get the answer by observing that: $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i}{(i+1)!} = \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i!}-\frac{1}{(i+1)!}= \frac{1}{1!} - \frac{1}{2!} +  \frac{1}{2!} - \frac{1}{3!} + \frac{1}{3!} - \frac{1}{4!} + \ldots + \frac{1}{n!} - \frac{1}{(n+1)!} = 1 - \frac{1}{(n+1)!}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not the correct formula. It should be:

$$\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{2}{3!}+...+\frac{n}{(n+1)!}=\frac{(n+1)!-1}{(n+1)!}$$

Now the base case works. For the inductive step you need to prove:

$$\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{2}{3!}+...+\frac{k+1}{(k+2)!}=\frac{(k+2)!-1}{(k+2)!} \qquad \mathrm{given}$$

$$\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{2}{3!}+...+\frac{k}{(k+1)!}=\frac{(k+1)!-1}{(k+1)!}$$

If you need a hint, leave a comment.

Also, please, do not write for $n=n+1$. Write $n=k+1$ instead.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an alternate proof, with generating functions instead of induction.
Note that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i}{(i+1)!}
$$
is the sum of the first $n$ terms of the series
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{i x^i}{(i+1)!}
&= x \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{i x^{i-1}}{(i+1)!} \\
&= x \frac{d}{dx} \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{x^i}{(i+1)!} \\
&= x \frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{x} \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{x^{i+1}}{(i+1)!} \\
&= x \frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{x} \left[ e^x - x - 1\right] \\
&= x \frac{d}{dx} \left[ \frac{e^x}{x} - 1 - \frac{1}{x} \right] \\
&= x \left[ \frac{xe^x - e^x}{x^2} + \frac{1}{x^2} \right] \\
&= \frac{xe^x - e^x + 1}{x}.
\end{align*}
To get the generating function for the sum of the first $n$ terms,
we then multiply by $\frac{1}{1 - x}$:
\begin{align*}
\frac{xe^x - e^x + 1}{x(1-x)}
&= \frac{(1 - e^x)(1 - x) + x}{x(1-x)} \\
&= \frac{1}{1-x} - \frac{e^x - 1}{x} \\
\end{align*}
The $n$th term of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ is $1$ and the $n$th term of $\frac{e^x - 1}{x}$ is $\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$, so the result is
$$
\boxed{1 - \frac{1}{(n+1)!}}
$$
as desired.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the key part of the induction argument (moving from the left-hand side of $n=k+1$ to the right-hand side):
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\frac{i}{(i+1)!} &= \sum_{i=1}^k\frac{i}{(i+1)!}+\frac{k+1}{(k+2)!}\tag{by defn. of $\Sigma$}\\[1em]
&= \frac{(k+1)!-1}{(k+1)!}+\frac{k+1}{(k+2)!}\tag{by ind. hyp.}\\[1em]
&= \frac{(k+2)[(k+1)!-1]}{(k+2)!}+\frac{k+1}{(k+2)!}\tag{manipulate}\\[1em]
&= \frac{(k+2)(k+1)!-k-2+k-1}{(k+2)!}\tag{expand}\\[1em]
&= \frac{(k+2)!-1}{(k+2)!}.\tag{simplify}
\end{align}
Could you follow all of the steps in how the right-hand side was reaching starting from the left-hand side? Do you see how the inductive hypothesis was used? Etc.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{2}{3!}+...+\frac{n}{(n+1)!}=\frac{(n+1)!-1}{(n+1)!} $$ 
Name as $p(n)$
1 step:$$n=1 \to p(1):\frac{1}{2!}=\frac{2!-1}{2!} $$
2nd step :assume $$n=k \to p(k):\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{2}{3!}+...+\frac{k}{(k+1)!}=\frac{(k+1)!-1}{(k+1)!} $$

3rd step :prove for n=k+1 $$n=k+1 \to p(k+1)=\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{2}{3!}+...+\frac{k}{(k+1)!}+\frac{k+1}{(k+2)!}=\frac{(k+2)!-1}{(k+2)!}$$ so substitute $\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{2}{3!}+...+\frac{k}{(k+1)!}={\color{Red}{\frac{(k+1)!-1}{(k+1)!} }}$ into p(k+1)

$${\color{Red}{\frac{(k+1)!-1}{(k+1)!} }}+\frac{k+1}{(k+2)!}=\\\frac{(k+1)!-1}{(k+1)!}*\frac{k+2}{k+2}+\frac{k+1}{(k+2)!} =\\\frac{(k+1)!(k+2)-1(k+2)}{(k+2)!}+\frac{k+1}{(k+2)!}=\\ \frac{(k+1)!(k+2)-1(k+2)+(k+1)}{(k+2)!} =\\\frac{(k+1)!(k+2)-1}{(k+2)!} =\\\frac{(k+2)!-1}{(k+2)!} $$ the proof is complete now (by induction)